# grid [x][y] is actually grid[y][x] in python, my teacher told me but it didn't make sense to me

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, matrix, grid

So if a matrix is given:

```
A= [ [0,0,0],
     [1,1,1] ,
     [2,2,2] ]
```

To access first element of matrix I should say A[x][y] or A[row][col]=A[0][0]=0 means first row which is represented by x and col is represented by y but today he made a sum of all paths on a grid program in which he was using grid [y][x] to navigate the next move; i.e. y was deciding either to move right or left or x to decide if he were to move up and down which is weird. Although I do know that you can even write it as grid [x][y] but his program made sense but I'm still confused how y is behaving as x in python. Can someone please clarify.

**His Program, incase you are interested**

```
def NP(row, col):
    def nop(y, x):
        if y == 0 and x == col:
            return 1
        count = []
        # set current point as visited
        grid[y][x] = 1
        if y - 1 >= 0:
          # checking upward
            if grid[y-1][x] == 0:
                count.append(nop(y-1, x))
          # checking downward
        if y + 1 <= row:
            if grid[y + 1][x] == 0:
                count.append(nop(y+1, x))
          # checking Left
        if x - 1 >= 0:
            if grid[y][x - 1] == 0:
                count.append(nop(y, x-1))
          # checking right
        if x + 1 <= col:
            if grid[y][x + 1] == 0:
                count.append(nop(y, x+1))
        # set current point as unvisited
        grid[y][x] = 0
        return sum(count)
    grid = []
    for i in range(row+1):
        line = []
        for j in range(col+1):
            line.append(0)
        grid.append(line)
    return nop(0, 0)

print(NP(1, 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

`x` and `y` are just variable names, it doesn't matter what you call them. If you notice, the up/down check is still done by decreasing/increasing the first `[ ]` (corresponding to row) and left/right is the second `[ ]` (corresponding to column). So it is the same logic, just consistently naming the variables differently.

Comment: I whole heartedly agree that to move up, code is using y and to move right or left, code is using x but if you see the coordinates of the grid it is now grid[y][x] instead of grid[x][y] and as a i shown earlier, it intuitively makes sense to use grid[row][col] or grid[x][y] when it comes to accessing an element but here somehow to navigate the elements in the matrix, you have to assume that it is now grid[y][x].

Comment: Correct, your intuition being `grid[x][y]` makes sense, but like I said `x` and `y` are just names. If I say `grid[y][x]`, the program sees no difference - `grid[y]` refers to the row (i.e. nested list) at index `y` and `(grid[y])[x]` means it gets the value at index `x` of that nested list. No matter what you name these variables, their integer values follow the same pattern, which is why the code works the same. Just swap every usage of x and y if you want it to match your intuition.

Comment: It is possible your teacher went with `grid[y][x]` because it matches a 2D coordinate system (4th quadrant). Top left element is origin, y axis goes down and x axis goes to the right. However, such a visualization is just for their understanding, not how the computer looks at it.